# Trying to access array offset on value of type int in - For each loop

Tags: php

So in my code, I have 2 functions. One that will return all rows in a table and one that will return 1 row based on its `code`.

When I run the function to get all of them - no issues - works and displays on the html fine using a `foreach` loop.

When i run the function however to get one, i get the error in the title for each line the array is referenced e.g `$location['address_line2']`.

I understand this is an error with a newer version of php but cannot find a work around.

The query works fine btw, I use `print_r` to display it before the foreach loop and i can see it in the inspect element.

```
$premises = getPremisesByCode($connection, $premisesCode);
//$premises = getAllPremises($connection);

if($premises != NULL){
  foreach ($premises as $location) {
    $visible = ($location['active'] != 'deactivated' ? '<span class="fa-stack"><i style="color: #008d1b;" class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x"></i></span>' : '<span class="fa-stack"><i style="color: #8d0000;" class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x"></i></span>' );

    $editBtn = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-info px-2 py-1 shadow" href="/'.$productfolder.'/edit-product-type/'.$location['code'].'/" title="Edit this product"><i style="font-size: 1rem;" class="mdi mdi-lead-pencil"></i></a>&nbsp;';

    $toggleIcon = ($location['active'] != 'deactivated') ? '<i class="mdi mdi-close"></i>' : '<i class="mdi mdi-check"></i>';
    $toggleColour = ($location['active'] != 'deactivated') ? 'warning' : 'success';
    $toggleBtn = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-'.$toggleColour.' px-2 py-1 shadow" href="/'.$productfolder.'/toggle-premises/'.$location['code'].'/">'.$toggleIcon.'</a>&nbsp;';

    $ptImage = (isset($location['logo'])) ? '<img class="img-thumbnail shadow mx-auto d-block p-2" style="max-width: 200px; background-color: '.$location['primary_colour'].' " src="/assets/images/'.$location['logo'].'">' : '<strong>No Image Uploaded!</strong>';

    $locationAddress = $location['address_line1'].'<br>';
    $locationAddress .= ($location['address_line2'] != '') ? $location['address_line2'].'<br>' : NULL;
    $locationAddress .= ($location['address_city'] != '') ? $location['address_city'].'<br>': NULL;
    $locationAddress .= $location['address_county'].'<br>';
    $locationAddress .= $location['address_postal_code'].'<br>';

    $outputTr .= '
      <tr id="'.$location['id'].'">
        <td width="100px">'.$editBtn.$toggleBtn.'</td>
        <td>'.$ptImage.'</td>
        <td>'.$location['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$locationAddress.$premisesCode.'</td>
        <td>'.$visible.'</td>
      </tr>';
  }
```

Comment: Check what `$premises` contains before the loop, it may be that there is only 1 and so it is an array of the details and not an array of premises.

Comment: @NigelRen It returns one, but because it is in a foreach, should it not be happy to just go through it once?

Comment: Not as it stands, you could make it an array when you fetch the data - `$premises = [ getPremisesByCode($connection, $premisesCode) ];`

Comment: @NigelRen Shouldn't it already return an array because it's a row?

Comment: @NigelRen Putting it in an array worked, thanks!

Comment: It is an array, but doing `foreach()` over it will loop over the individual fields in the array.

Comment: If you know you're only getting one premise details, why would you `foreach()` through it? You _could_, as long as your `getPremisesbyCode()` function returns a 2-d array, but what's the point?

Comment: @droopsnoot Because there could be one, or many

Comment: Ah, OK. So you mean your code might have got all the premises, or just one. I wasn't considering anything outside the code posted. Makes sense.

Comment: Check the count and if needed use loop else just show the result. Or make getPremisesByCode return and array with one result.

Comment: And when $location['address_city'] is empty don't concatenate: NULL instead use an empty string